# How to update a lookup value in a Document Library With DocumentSet

Tags: powershell, lookup-column, document-set

I would like to update my document library but i do not know how to do with one of my field which is a lookup field. Here is my code:

```
#plug-in SP PS 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Variables
$WebURLp="http://myparentsite"
$WebURLc="http://myparentsite/mychildsite"

#Get Web and List objects
$Webp = Get-SPWeb $WebURLp
$Webc = Get-SPWeb $WebURLc
$ParentProducts = $Webp.Lists.tryGetList("PRODUCTS") 
$ChildRecipe = $Webc.Lists.tryGetList("RECIPE") 
$spContentType = $ChildRecipe .ContentTypes["New Recipe"]

#Search if Recip exist
$RecipName = "My FIRST RECIP"
$RecipDetail = "Cold Recip"
$RecipLetter = "R"
$DocSetName = "R320_" + $RecipName + $RecipLetter 

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$targetFolder = $Webc.GetFolder($ChildRecipe .RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/$DocSetName")
#Build properties hash table from $docSetInfos[]
[Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{}

#CREATE A RECIP FOLDER
if (-not $targetFolder.Exists)
{

$RefRecip= "R320"
$RecipDetail = "Cold Recip"
##Build properties hash table from $docSetInfos[]
#[Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{}
$docsetProperties.Add('v_ref',$RefRecip)
$docsetProperties.Add('v_name',$RecipName)
$docsetProperties.Add('v_detail',$RecipDetail )
$newDocumentSet =   [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($targetFolder.ParentFolder,$DocSetName,$spContentType.Id,$docsetProperties)
}

#UPDATE RECIP FOLDER
$docsetProperties.Add('v_box',"BOXRECIP")
$docsetProperties.Add('v_cat',"208 - vegetable")
#LOOKUP
$LookupValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection

#Get a Lookup Item from Parent List
$ParentProductsItem= $ParentProducts.Items | where {$_["Category"] -eq "208 - vegetable"}
$LookupValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue
$LookupValue.LookupId = $ParentProjectItem.ID
$LookupValues.Add($LookupValue) #Add to Collection

#MAJ Lookup
$docsetProperties.Add('v_cat_lookup',$LookupValues)
$targetFolder.Update()
```

Nothing happens, no code error but no update done :(

Answer (score 0):

Use object type SPFieldLookupValue to update. A helpful docu might be [this one here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1533/update-lookup-field-programmatically-in-sharepoint.aspx)

Comment: Thx, I got it finaly :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally because i had 2 problems to solve :

- my code was not appropriate in the Update part of my document-Set
- I was not using the good function for the lookup value

Here is my correct code :

```
#plug-in SP PS 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Variables
$WebURLp="http://myparentsite"
$WebURLc="http://myparentsite/mychildsite"

#Get Web and List objects
$Webp = Get-SPWeb $WebURLp
$Webc = Get-SPWeb $WebURLc
$ParentProducts = $Webp.Lists.tryGetList("PRODUCTS") 
$ChildRecipe = $Webc.Lists.tryGetList("RECIPE") 
$spContentType = $ChildRecipe .ContentTypes["New Recipe"]

#Search if Recip exist
$RecipName = "My FIRST RECIP"
$RecipDetail = "Cold Recip"
$RecipLetter = "R"
$DocSetName = "R320_" + $RecipName + $RecipLetter 

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$targetFolder = $Webc.GetFolder($ChildRecipe .RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/$DocSetName")
#Build properties hash table from $docSetInfos[]
[Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{}

#CREATE A RECIP FOLDER
if (-not $targetFolder.Exists)
{
$RefRecip= "R320"
$RecipDetail = "Cold Recip"
##Build properties hash table from $docSetInfos[]
#[Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{}
$docsetProperties.Add('v_ref',$RefRecip)
$docsetProperties.Add('v_name',$RecipName)
$docsetProperties.Add('v_detail',$RecipDetail )
$newDocumentSet =   [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($targetFolder.ParentFolder,$DocSetName,$spContentType.Id,$docsetProperties)
}
else
{
$newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::GetDocumentSet($targetFolder)
}

#UPDATE RECIP FOLDER
$item = $newDocumentSet.Item
$item['v_box'] = "BOXRECIP"
$item['v_cat'] ="208 - vegetable"

#LOOKUP
$LookupValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue

#Get a Lookup Item from Parent List
$ParentProductsItem= $ParentProducts.Items | where {$_["Category"] -eq "208 - vegetable"}
$LookupValue.LookupId = $ParentProjectItem.ID

#MAJ Lookup
$item['v_cat_lookup'] = $LookupValue
$item.Update()
```